How to type the dash ("–") character using the standard US keyboard layout?
If I type --  in OpenOffice/LibreOffice, then it gets automatically replaced by – . But elsewhere, is there an easy way to type this character?
(I'm interested in solutions that will continue working through upgrades)

What worked for me was:

Hold Ctrl + Shift and press the 'u' key
Release the Ctrl, Shift, and 'u' keys
You will see the letter 'u' on the screen
Type the hex code for the Unicode character, in this case 2014 for the em dash
Press the Enter key and the em dash will replace the letter 'u'

like so:
—
